# Drawing circle with stroke and fill color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

how to draw a circle using CGContextAddArc with different sroke color and fill color?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wouldn't something like this work?

```
CGContextAddArc(ctx, x, y, 1.0, 0, 2 * Pi, 1); // Or is it 2 * M_PI?

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, fillColor);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, strokeColor);
CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

Comment: CGContextAddArc needs 7 arguments. Only 6 supplied. Last argument should be a 1 or a 0 for clockwise/ant-clockwise arc: CGContextAddArc(ctx, x, y, 1.0, 0, 2 * M_PI, 1);